# In-place RGB->BGR color conversion is slower in OpenCV

Tags: performance, opencv, memory, in-place

Is it the case that the in-place RGB->BGR color conversion routine in OpenCV saves some memory, but takes longer? If yes, can anyone explain why?

My application calls the cv::cvtColor(srcMat, dstMat, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR) routine in OpenCV (version 4.2.0). In an effort to make the application faster, I tried the in-place version of this routine (by invoking it with the same Mat object for source and destination). I expected the speed to slightly improve, since the in-place version does not allocate new memory.

To test my expectation, I ran my application in a loop over 10,000 250x250 RGB images. To my surprise, my application became slower when the in-place version was used. In fact, I saw that the larger the image (500x500 vs 250x250), the greater the difference between the in-place and regular version.

Is this expected? If so, is it because the in-place version does a swap operation (more statements) and the regular version is only a copy operation?

Would anyone be willing to try to reproduce this behavior? It can be done so easily by timing the following snippet in 2 different ways: 1) use the snippet below, and 2) following the brief instructions in the comments in the snippet for the in-place version.

```
// Read image
Mat srcMat = imread(filename);

// Comment out this line for the in-place version
Mat dstMat;

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
  // Use srcMat instead of dstMat in the in-place version
  cv::cvtColor(srcMat, dstMat, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What CPU are you experiencing this on, and perhaps even OS? What sort of build of OpenCV are you using? | Good question, but it's going to be quite difficult to answer.

Comment: CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2450 v2 @ 2.50GHz. It has 16 hyper-threaded cores. My application runs 32 threads, each (parallel) thread processing a single image. OS: Unix. Optimized build of OpenCV with ICC compiler.

Comment: I guess this is an operation in some sort of processing loop. In that case, instead of doing it in-place I'd just have a `Mat` that persists across iterations, and use that for destination of the `cvtColor`. As long as the destination has the correct datatype and size, it won't get reallocated. Generally this is the case, and the extra memory is not likely to be critical. | Oh, 32 of them in parallel, i guess it might matter a bit more in that scenario :)

Comment: Is there a way you could try it with the most recent release of OpenCV? Maybe [edit] the question with a short [mcve] that will allow others to easily reproduce it. And I'd suggest creating an issue in the opencv issue tracker on github, if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: I can look into the most recent version, but it will take a good bit of work to compile my application with a different OpenCV version. Edited the question to add more details for reproduction. Thanks!

Comment: In-place processing prevents some compilation (and execution) optimizations due to [loop carried dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_dependence_analysis). I can't say this is the explanation here, but it could be.

Comment: I think the inplace version might allocate new memory for every call of the function, while the src-dst version allocates menory only once if you keep the dst matrix buffer (and images size doesnt change) This is obvious for stuff like gaussianBlur etc. but might happen in cvtColor as well.

Comment: @DanMašek Following up, I have now tried a destination matrix that persists across iterations. The performance of this new version is better than the in-place version (where srcMat and dstMat are the same), but it's still slightly worse than the regular version. I'm still investigating all of this, but so far, it seems that not allocating memory for the destination matrix isn't improving performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may dig in the sources for finding the reason.

There are few possible code path (Using OpenCL or not, using IPP or not).
In my machine the execution of `cv::cvtColor` reaches the function `CvtColorIPPLoopCopy` in [color.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.hpp):

```c++
template <typename Cvt>
bool CvtColorIPPLoopCopy(const uchar * src_data, size_t src_step, int src_type, uchar * dst_data, size_t dst_step, int width, int height, const Cvt& cvt)
{
    Mat temp;
    Mat src(Size(width, height), src_type, const_cast<uchar*>(src_data), src_step);
    Mat source = src;
    if( src_data == dst_data )
    {
        src.copyTo(temp);
        source = temp;
    }
    bool ok;
    parallel_for_(Range(0, source.rows),
                  CvtColorIPPLoop_Invoker<Cvt>(source.data, source.step, dst_data, dst_step,
                                               source.cols, cvt, &ok),
                  source.total()/(double)(1<<16) );
    return ok;
}
```

The code checks if `src_data == dst_data`, and if equal it copies the source image into temporary image:

```c++
if( src_data == dst_data )
{
    src.copyTo(temp);
    source = temp;
}
```

The extra data copy may be the reason for in-place processing taking longer time.

---

Note:
I can't say this is the reason for sure, because there are other possible code paths.
There are many highly performance optimized functions that do not support "in-place" processing.
When OpenCV needs to execute a function that doesn't support "in-place" processing the solution may be copying the source image to temporary location.
The same practice may be used for other execution code paths.

As I commented,
In-place processing prevents some compilation (and execution) optimizations due to loop carried dependencies.
In some cases there are also parallelization issues regarding "in-place" processing.
That's the reason many optimized "primitive" functions do not support "in-place" processing.